# How to find regexp in a string and attach it to a variable

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have a string in JavaScript "This is a nice website - http://stackoverflow.com". I want to extract the URL along with the three preceding characters (space dash space) using RegExp and attach the extracted string to a variable.

var string = "This is a nice website - http://stackoverflow.com";

var reg = ""; //no idea how to write this regexp for extracting url and three preceding chars

// and after some magic I would get

var extracedString = " - http://www.stackoverflow.com";

Anyone? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the URL, or you want to match any URL?

Comment: I want to mach any URL at the end of a string along with "space dash space" in the front of the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var extractedString = string.replace(/^.*(...http:.+)$/, "$1");

if (extractedString == string) {
  alert("No match");
}
```

The dot `.` matches every character, so three dots match three arbitrary characters. The `^` and `$` match start and end of the string.

Note, that this won't work for

- more than one URL
- HTTPS, mailto, FTP, SSH, ... (although you can simply expand it, like this: `(https?|ftp|ssh)`)